# Stop Windows Remote Desktop via .bat file

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Is there a possibility to disable the Windows XP SP2 Remote Desktop feature with a .bat file? I already tried to find a service and just stop and start it but I had no luck.

The background is that I have to run time critical tests on a remote pc, and I have to make sure that nobody is logging in while a test is running. The PC needs a network connection so I need something Remote Desktop specific.

Answer (score 6):

Disable Remote Desktop:

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v "fDenyTSConnections" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
```

Enable Remote Desktop:

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v "fDenyTSConnections" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f
```

It's worth noting that if you're using Group Policy to enable Remote Desktop, you should just use Group Policy to disable it.  Else, you will need to tickle this key/value instead :

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\fDenyTSConnections`

Comment: Will that terminate existing sessions though?

Comment: @Steve No, it only *disables Remote Desktop*, as per OP's question. If disconnecting active session is also a requirement, they should update their question's details.

Comment: @JScott - do either/both of those registry changes require restarting Windows to take effect?

Comment: @mfinni No restart required, changing the value will immediately enable/disable Remote Desktop access.

Comment: There are two nice command line utilities exists with Windows 2000+: qwinsta.exe and rwinsta.exe (*Q*uery *WI*ndows *STA*tion and *R*eset *WN*dows *STA*tion respectively). First one query Terminal Services/Remote Desktop Server and enumerates sessions, the second one allows to terminate session by session ID. I think using together it with REG cmd to disable Remote Desktop as specified above by jscott - i'ts a complete solution

Comment: Also you can use tsdiscon.exe utility to disconnect any sessions (incl. your local console session)

Comment: tsdiscon.exe won't end the sessions.  If he truly wants to avoid the impact of having users logged in, it's better to end the sessions using rwinsta.exe.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the following script is exactly what you need.

```
   REM ** Disable new logons
   change logon /disable
   REM ** Throw out all existing sessions by resetting the listener session
   for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('qwinsta ^| find /i "listen"') do echo y | rwinsta %%i
   REM ** Maintenance jobs like backup comes here
   REM ** start /wait ensures that this job waits until the command
   REM ** is executed completely before going on to the next command
   start /wait <your maintenance command comes here>
   REM ** Maintenance is finished. Let users in again
   change logon /enable
```

http://ts.veranoest.net/ts_faq_administration.htm#reset_sessions

Comment: That's nice too.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was wrong on this point:

> You can't, AFAIK. There is no service
>   for this.

But this one still holds true.

> You could block the RDP listening
>   port, default is 3389.